# How do bats manage lymph fluids?

Tags: physiology, mammals, blood-circulation, lymphatic-system

We all know that bats hang upside down to sleep. I was watching some sleep for a while, and they don't move much while asleep.

If I fall asleep sitting in a chair my lower legs will swell. Lymph fluids in people are mostly moved by muscles in the limbs of the body.

It would seem like a sleeping bats lymph fluids would gather at or near the head, chest and lungs.

How do bats manage lymph fluids?